# Blackberry Screen Transitions on close

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hey everyone,
I'm doing a Blackberry App compatible with OS4.5+ and I'd like to do some screen transitions. I know how to do them through the screen's sublayout method when I push a screen to the UiApplication, but when I wan't to make one disappear (like when I press the back button), I can't seem to find anything.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to override the onClose() method on each of your screens.

Comment: I tried this Michael, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in code :( kept getting an IllegalState exception. Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do transitions for 4.5. But, since Blackberry API the [`setTransition`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngineInstance.html#setTransition%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.TransitionContext%29) method from `UiEngineInstance` class might help you.

EDIT:
It appears I misunderstood the question. Here's another idea: You said you know how to do the transition when you push the screen. Do that when you go back also. You can pop the old screen and then push it again and this way you will be able to handle transitions.

Comment: Yes you can do transition, you just need to code them yourself. His question is about closing a screen with a transition.